# Smooth maps on manifold with nonconstant push forward maps

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

I am a beginner in manifold. I am reading Push forward map ( or differential map at a point). I came across the following question:

Give smooth maps $F: M \to \mathbb{R^3}$ and $G: N \to \mathbb{R^3}$ where Manifolds $M$ and $N$ are not open subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that the push forward maps induced a point $p$, that is $F_{*},p : T_{p}M \to T_{p} \mathbb{R^3}$ and $G_{*},p : T_{p}N \to T_{p} \mathbb{R^3}$ are not constant maps.

My attempt:

My idea is to take $M=S^3$( which is not open in $\mathbb{R^3})$ now I tried to define a smooth map $F: M \to \mathbb{R^3}$ but I got stuck.

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: What's the relationship between $M$ and $N$ in the question?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, there is no relation. It is just that I need two different such smooth maps.

Comment: I see.  Here's a hint then.  For $M = S^3 = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4: \sum x_i^2 = 1\}$, can you show that$F:S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is smooth?  Moreover, can you show that for every $p\in S^3$, $F_\ast,p$ is non-constant?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, could you please give me a second such map.

Comment: Does the map $F(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})=(x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$ will also work?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure it's different enough to count as a second one.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Okay could you think of some different such map?

Comment: Do you have to continue using $S^3$?  If so, here's a general way to construct smooth maps from $S^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $F:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be any smooth map (for example, it could be a different polynomial in all three coordinates).  Then restricting $F$ to $S^3$ gives a smooth map.  (But, depending on the starting $F$, not all $p\in S^3$ will necessarily have $F_\ast,p$ non-constant.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito, I do not necessarily require to be my manifold as $S^3$. Any manifold is fine ( which is not open as a subspace of Euclidean space)

Comment: How about if I take the relation $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_4 =1$?

Comment: How is that relation a function from $S^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, I mean if I choose my manifold to be $M=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4): x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 =1\}$  and define $F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. Now does this map is smooth with nonconstant diffferential?

Comment: That should work!